# Jquery buttons background color alternate

Tags: jquery

I have a list of `for` and `against` buttons. What i'm trying to do is if `for` is clicked , the `against` button for that row has alternate colors.  I've tried to do this with jquery but it isn't working. How do i fix this? Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mdanz/9H9qE/1/

```
    <style type="text/css">
.rate3 {
padding:5px;
font-family:Arial;
color:#FFFFFF;
cursor:pointer;
background-color:red;
border:1px solid #000000;
}

.rate4 {
padding:5px;
font-family:Arial;
color:#FFFFFF;
cursor:pointer;
background-color:red;
border:1px solid #000000;
}

.vote {
height:30px;
width:auto;
margin-bottom:10px;

}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.rate3').live('click',function() {

    $(this).css('background-color','#FFFFFF');
        $(this).css('color','red');
        $(this).parent('div').next('.rate4').css('background-color','red');
        $(this).parent('div').next('.rate4').css('color','#FFFFFF');

}

$('.rate4').live('click',function() {

    $(this).css('background-color','#FFFFFF');
        $(this).css('color','red');
        $(this).parent('div').next('.rate3').css('background-color','red');
        $(this).parent('div').next('.rate3').css('color','#FFFFFF');

}
</script>
<?php for($i=0;$i<11;$i++) {  ?>
<div class="vote"><a class="rate3">For</a> <a class="rate4">Against</a></div>

<?php  } ?>
```

Comment: what's your alternate color? it looks like you're only using red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `.live('click')` because you aren't dynamically modifying the DOM with jQuery, so just use `.click()`.

This code should work:

```
$('.vote a').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().css({
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        color: 'white'
    });
    $(this).css({
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        color: 'red'
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9H9qE/19/

---

But I'd prefer to do this with classes, as it's much cleaner (and easier) to mess with stylesheets:

```
$('.vote a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

And the appropriate CSS:

```
.selected {
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9H9qE/22/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('a').click(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is('.rate3')){
            c = '.rate4';
        }
        else {
            c = '.rate3';
        }

        $(this).closest('.vote').find(c).css({
            backgroundColor : '#fff'
        });
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9H9qE/9/).

Answer (score 0):

To add to Blender's answer, you can also clean-up how you're setting the CSS properties like so:

```
$(this).css({
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    color: 'red'
});
```

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/9H9qE/16/).